# Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) not working as it should?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the mouses world position when the camera position changes and the camera orthographic size changes as well.

Right now the code looks like the following:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    var mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(mouse, 10, greenery);
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Collider2D c = null;
    Debug.Log(colliders.Length);
    foreach (var cd in colliders)
    {
        Debug.Log(Vector2.Distance(mouse, cd.transform.position));
        if (Vector2.Distance(mouse, cd.transform.position) < distance)
        {
            Debug.Log(cd.gameObject);
            c = cd;
        }
    }
}
```

it is trying to find the closest object within the "greenery" layermask.
It does not do this as it picks an object that seems random.

Here are some images:

[image: Before click]

[image: After click]

The third red bush from the left has been removed and not the one that is hovered over.
I am unsure what my problem is
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609191/7111561) about you never re-assigning `distance`:

Generally it is cheaper using [`sqrMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-sqrMagnitude.html) instead of [`Vector2.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html) (= [`magnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-magnitude.html)) as it additionally needs to take the square root. If the exact distance doesn't matter but you only want to compare them (and since distances are always positive) you can rely on

```
magnitudeA < magnitudeB <=> magnitudeA² < magnitudeB²
```

and then further within the loop you should only calculate this **once** and reuse the value!

So you should rather use e.g.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    Vector2 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(mouse, 10, greenery);
    float smallestSqrDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Collider2D closestCollider = null;
    foreach (var cd in colliders)
    {
        var sqrDistance = (mouse - (Vector2)cd.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (sqrDistance < smallestSqrDistance)
        {
            closestCollider = cd;
            smallestSqrDistance = sqrDistance;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

If you are open to use `Linq` you could also write this simply as

```
using System.Linq;

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
{
    Vector2 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)
    var colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(mouse, 10, greenery);

    var closestCollider = colliders.OrderBy(c => (mouse - (Vector2)c.transform.position).sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();
   
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue that you're having is that in the foreach loop you're testing against a variable called 'distance' that you set to be infinity. All the loop is returning is the last collider in the array returned from the OverlapCircle.

I think you need to add a line in the if() statement so it looks like -

```
if (Vector2.Distance(mouse, cd.transform.position) < distance)
        {
            Debug.Log(cd.gameObject);
            c = cd;
            distance = Vector2.Distance(mouse, cd.transform.position); 
        }
```

this will update the value of 'distance' to the current shortest distance measured.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! My mind must have had a mental blank when coding this, would there be a more efficient way of doing this, do you think?

Comment: @Jerry there is more efficient way see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76610323/7111561)